# promener leur regard sur / d'un visage à l'autre

Tags: prépositions

> Ils promènent leur regard tantôt **sur** mon visage, tantôt **sur** celui du
> gardien.
>
> Ils promènent leur regard **de** mon visage **à** celui du gardien et vice
> versa.

Est-il possible de dire « promener le regard **d**'un visage **à** l'autre » ?

Comment: À mon avis la dernière proposition est sans nul doute la meilleure.

Comment: Larousse: elle promène son regard **sur la foule**. Et bien je suis allée consulter le Larousse, et voilà. Apparemment, comme sur la pelouse.  Alors, la première est la bonne si on suit le dico.

Comment: @None Merci. :) Lambie, oui, je crois que la première phrase est possible.

Comment: Les trois sont possibles et correctes grammaticalement mais celle qui « sonne » le mieux et  la moins maladroite à mon aivs, est la dernière, dans le contexte d'un regard qui passe de l'un à l'autre visage. Sinon bien entendu, on peut porter/promener son regard sur quelque chose.

Answer (score 2):

1. *Ils promènent leur regard tantôt sur mon visage, tantôt sur celui du gardien.*

   C'est une tournure possible. Ils regardent mon front, mes yeux, ma bouche, mes joues, etc, puis même chose pour le visage gardien, et ainsi de suite.
2. *Ils promènent leur regard de mon visage à celui du gardien et vice versa.*

   C'est possible aussi. Ils me regardent, puis leurs regards se dirigent lentement vers le gardien, et réciproquement.

Voici d'autres manières de le dire :

> *Ils observent alternativement nos visages.
>
> Ils nous dévisagent l'un et l'autre.
>
> Ils scrutent tour à tour nos visages.*

Comment: Merci beaucoup. _Ils nous dévisagent l'un et l'autre._ ne veut-elle pas dire qu'au début, ils me dévisagent, puis ils dévisagent l'autre personne, sans diriger à nouveau leur regard vers moi ?

Comment: @Oreste C'est vrai, on perd l'idée explicite d'allers-retours successifs, mais la phrase ne les interdit pas non plus, c'est laissé à l'imagination du lecteur.

Answer (score 1):

Je ne pense pas qu'un visage soit quelque chose d'assez vaste pour que le regard puisse véritablement se déplacer d'un point à un autre, à moins de se trouver—et dans ce cas la métaphore peut être considérée comme excellente—très près de la personne dont on regarde le visage.

Dans la page de recherche « [elle promenait son regard](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22elle%20promenait%20son%20regard%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) » on trouve  le rare exemple suivant, dans lequel la condition de proximité est très probablement réalisée. Dans tous les autres cas, ou pour le moins, dans l'énorme majorité de ces cas, l'espace sur lequel le regard se déplace est très grand : « sur la foule, à la ronde, autour d'elle, sur la pièce, sur les lieux, sur le temple, de l'un à l'autre, sur la prairie, etc. ».

- ([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/La_raison_du_c%C5%93ur/Ntr5DwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22elle+promenait+son+regard%22&pg=PT87&printsec=frontcover)) Ce sentiment s'intensifiait quand elle promenait son regard sur le visage de Lance, illuminé par les flammes dansantes.

Il est  apparent que pour la première des phrases questionnées le contexte de grande proximité n'a rien de plausible ; évidemment, considérant le cas extrême d'une situation où ces quatre individus sont ligotés plus ou moins les uns contre les autres (autour du fût d'une colonne sectionnée à hauteur de leur poitrine, par exemple) il existe alors un contexte. À moins d'un contexte qui remplisse cette condition la première phrase n'est pas une bonne idée.

La seconde phrase est sans problème, sauf en ce qui concerne le choix de « vice versa » (pas du meilleur style parce que « promener » dans ce contexte,   ne signifie pas « un passage de A à B ».

Selon le contexte l'une ou l'autre des phrases suivantes convient.

- Ils promènent leur regard de l'un à l'autre de nos visages.
- Ils promènent leur regard entre mon visage et celui du gardien.

Voir par exemple cette [page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22prom%C3%A8ne%20son%20regard%20entre%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) pour mieux se rendre compte de l'usage de « entre » avec la locution « promener son regard ».

« Promener leur regard d'un visage à l'autre » est correct.

([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Les_Dangers_d_un_patronyme/8BmWDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22elle+promenait+son+regard%22&pg=PT361&printsec=frontcover)) (elle promenait son regard de l'un à l'autre des visages dans une attention très soutenue, à la recherche d'un trait commun)

Comment: Je vous remercie pour votre réponse. // _Quatre têtes qui ont un air de famille et qui promènent leur regard **tantôt sur le voisin, tantôt sur le visiteur**, semblant se parler ou s'adresser à lui sans qu'aucune voix ne soit audible._ [source](http://www.cliquezgenereusement.com/gardeTetes.html) // _en particulier à cause de l'imparfait_ --- Mes phrases sont au présent.

Comment: @Oreste « promener son regard sur une personne » semble acceptable.